# NullPointerException при добавлении Toolbar. Android

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

Имеется следующий код:

```
package asus.example.com.fitnessapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ProgramActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_program);
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        String PROGRAM = "PROGRAM";
        String path = getIntent().getStringExtra(PROGRAM);
        imageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(path, "drawable", getPackageName()));
        readFromFile(path);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    private void readFromFile(String path){
        byte[] buffer = null;
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = getAssets().open(path);
            int size = inputStream.available();
            buffer = new byte[size];
            inputStream.read(buffer);
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String data = new String(buffer);
        textView.setText(data);
    }

}
```

При выполнении выдает ошибку:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{asus.example.com.fitnessapp/asus.example.com.fitnessapp.ProgramActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2581)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1502)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at asus.example.com.fitnessapp.ProgramActivity.onCreate(ProgramActivity.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1502) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

По дебагеру посмотрел - проблема на этой строке кода `Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

В чем проблема?

Вот xml файл этой активности

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProgramActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы работает с ActionBar, до того как выполнили:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Нужно перенести код, ниже этой строки.